# How do I add rounded corners to complex shapes in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, rounded-corners

How can I make the corners of a complex shape rounded in CSS? Similar to how VSCode rounds the corners of selected code. I know how to make a regular rectangle rounded in CSS but how do I join the rounded corners if the rectangles touch or intersect? If necessary, using JavaScript for this is also ok (just not canvas or something like that). Here's an example of how VSCode does it:

[image: example screenshot]

I've researched this and have only found a *lot* of solutions for rectangles but nothing about non-convex or even non-rectangular shapes.

Comment: I have done research on this and I have not found anything of use. Maybe I should have explained that in order to not get penalized?

Comment: You might want to explain what you mean by "complex shape". An SVG? A shape drawn on a canvas? what is "complex shape"?

Comment: Well, complex shapes are not exactly the same thing as highlighted text. If you did the research that you claim, you would have seen this about highlighted text: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985529/how-to-apply-rounded-borders-to-highlight-selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as pointed out in a comment, [How to apply rounded borders to highlight/selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985529/how-to-apply-rounded-borders-to-highlight-selection) answers the problem specifically for highlighted text. For other complex shapes (like literally, any other shape) I'll just have to settle on using canvas or SVG although that wasn't really the goal.